# Does $\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{ (\sin x\cos x )^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\rm d}x$ have a result with closed form?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Someone gives a few steps as follows 
\begin{align*} \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{ (\sin x\cos x )^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\rm d}x&=2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{ (\sin x\cos x )^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\rm d}x\\ &=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1-\cos 4x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\rm d}x(x=\sin t)\\ &=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} 1-\cos (4\sin t){\rm d}t\\ &=\frac{\pi}{24}-\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \cos (4\sin t){\rm d}t\\ &=\frac{\pi}{24}-\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-16)^n\sin^{2n} t}{(2n)!}{\rm d}t\\ \end{align*}

but it seems to be not able to go forward.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that in the range of integration $\sin(t)>0$, the antiderivative $$I_n=\int\frac{(-16)^n\sin^{2n} (t)}{(2n)!}\,dt=-\frac{(-16)^n \,\cos (t) \,\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}-n;\frac{3}{2};\cos
   ^2(t)\right)}{ (2 n)!}$$
$$J_n=\int_0^{\frac \pi 6 }\frac{(-16)^n\sin^{2n} (t)}{(2n)!}\,dt=(-1)^n\frac{ 2^{4 n-1} B_{\frac{1}{4}}\left(n+\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(2 n)!}$$

I have not been able to find a closed form solution for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty J_n$ but, evaluated numerically, it is $0.228223530$ (this number is not recongnized by inverse symbolic calculators) leading for the end result to $0.073843811$ which coincides with the result of the numerical integration of the expression in title.

**Edit**

If we consider the partial sums
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p J_n$$ they seem to converge quite fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
p & S_p= & S_p\approx \\
 0 & \frac{\pi }{6} & 0.5235987756 \\
 1 & \sqrt{3}-\frac{\pi }{2} & 0.1612544808 \\
 2 & -\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{\pi }{6} & 0.2349236410 \\
 3 & \frac{11}{10 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{7 \pi }{54} & 0.2278418040 \\
 4 & \frac{293}{420 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{\pi }{18} & 0.2282376197 \\
 5 & \frac{72017}{94500 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{91 \pi }{1350} & 0.2282231654 \\
 6 & \frac{784739}{1039500 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{803 \pi }{12150} & 0.2282235372 \\
 7 & \frac{1500798197}{1986484500 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{4379 \pi }{66150} & 0.2282235301 \\
 8 & \frac{9004353437}{11918907000 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{39407 \pi }{595350} & 0.2282235302
   \\
 9 & \frac{153074374241}{202621419000 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{3191983 \pi }{48223350} &
   0.2282235302 \\
 10 & \frac{93484698189481}{123743795175000 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{3799979 \pi }{57408750} &
   0.2282235302
\end{array}
\right)$$

Written as $S_p=a_p+\pi b_p$ both coefficients tend quite fast to their asymptotic values.